# Openlayers 2 projection different depending on how I ask for it

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a map and am trying to see what projection is set, but, depending on how I ask, I get two different values, this is what I see in the console:

```
> this.olMap.projection
< "EPSG:4326"

> this.olMap.getProjection()
< "EPSG:900913"
```

Is this expected? Which one is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`olMap.projection`](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html) is the default projection for layers that are added to the map, with a default value of `EPSG:4326`

[`olMap.getProjection`](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getProjection) is the projection of the map (the display)